# Terminology request: Graphs based on vector spaces

Tags: terminology, graph-theory

I am interested in graphs $G=(V,E)$ with vertex set $V$ a finite dimensional vector space and edges in $E$ which are not necessarily related to the linear structure of $V$. So my objects are just graphs with a vertex set with additional structure, and I don't require any special morphisms. (The vector space structure is for combinatorial reasons, to count vertices in terms of dimension.) I'd like to use a striking name for those graphs, but neither do I know if

1) there is already a name for them,

2) there would be collision with other terminology if I named them something like "vector graphs", "vector based graphs", etc.

For example "linear graph" would be a bad choice.

If some graph theory terminology specialist out there could help that would be very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Your set-up sounds reminiscent of work in algebraic combinatorics where people associate vector spaces to the rank levels of a graded poset (whose Hasse diagram is of course a graph) to help establish unimodality of the rank-generating function.  I'm not sure whether a special name is given to this extra vector space structure (except in the very nice case when these vector spaces turn out to be the weight spaces in a Lie algebra).  But you might find it interesting/useful to take a look e.g. at the following survey paper on this topic:

Richard Stanley, Some applications of algebra to combinatorics, Discrete Applied Math. 34 (1991), 241--277.

Comment: @Abel: my answer is mostly related to your parenthetical remark, which led me to believe you wanted a comma after "finite vertex set $V$" in the first line of your question -- which changes the meaning of the question a lot, I think. Anyway, my answer is based on that reading of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation reminds me of *vertex colored graphs*, that is graphs whose vertices are colored such that no two vertices of the same color share an edge. (See for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring ) You could then just use the dimension of the vector space associated to a vertex as its color. But it's not clear to me whether you objects satisfy this additional assumption on adjacency.

Comment: No, they don't. In fact there are colors involved, but they are fairly independent of the dimension.


Comment: well, then sorry for the not really helpful remark.